# Running Firefox browser in docker with Selenium Java

Tags: docker, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

I've ran into an issue where I can't seem to run selenium webdriver on a docker machine.

I have tried various version of the following, currently this is the config I have:

geckodriver=19.1
firefox:57.0
webdriver-selenium-java=3.8.1

Java code:

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/main/webdriver/geckodriver-v0.19.0-macos");

            return buildWebDriver(MarionetteDriver::new);
```

Docker Command line is:

```
ENTRYPOINT  xvfb-run env os=linux java -jar webscale-load-tester-*.jar
```

Current error is this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

I also set Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1024x768x16 & with same issue:

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to run our Selenium tests in parallel, we use selenium grid and with grid concept better to use docker. with Selenium Grid with Hub and Nodes concept register your docker node and your hub will execute your test in the docker node

for grid 
 //Set DesiredCapabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
 caps.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
 if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
 caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
 caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://169.254.228.41:444/wd/hub"),caps);
 driver.navigate().to("URL");
```

Please refer my block to configure docker node in case need help
https://samirqa.wordpress.com/2018/05/26/configure-selenium-grid-using-docker/